# NULL type of object in R

Tags: r, null

I am still a novice user in R, and have been reading Advanced R by Hadley to improve my R programming skills.

I came across this code in his book:

```
NULL>0
```

The output for this code is `logical(0)`.

I have two questions on this:

**Question 1**: What does `logical(0)` mean?

**Question 2**: I would have expected a TRUE/FALSE as the return value. This is  because he talks about the rules for coercion in R, specifically that Logical < Integer < Double < Character (Least flexible to most flexible). Hence, I assume that `NULL` is of type Logical.

I am not really sure where `NULL` fits into this equation. I'd appreciate any explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`logical(0)` is a logical vector of length zero. `NULL` is its own type, as `typeof(NULL)` shows, and does not contain anything, as `length(NULL)` shows.

It does not make sense to compare `NULL` to 0; it is not a numeric value, or even a value at all. There is no answer possible to the comparison, and therefore no logical value is returned, only an empty vector.

Consider for instance the output of:

```
c(TRUE, FALSE, NULL)
```

The `NULL` is ignored, rather than yielding an error or being converted. You should consider it as being literally nothing at all, contrary to `NA` which is an indication of a missing value of a certain type - try replacing `NULL` with `NA` in the above concatenation.